# d3 update selections: How does d3 decide which existing html elements to capture for its own use?

Tags: html, d3.js

**I’m new to d3 and I need some help understanding html element reuse.**

Here is a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/qmEBE/

I put an existing paragraph element in the body:

```
<body>
        <p> Old Text.</p>
</body>
```

Then I define a dataset of 3 numbers and do a .selectAll(“p”)  like this:

```
var dataset = [10,20,30];

d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("p")
    .text( function(d){ return("#"+d); } ) ;
```

I get this:

```
Old Text.
#20
#30
```

Two things trouble me:

Why did d3 not create a new p-tag and display the #10?

When I look at the pre-existing paragraph element (“Old Text”), d3 has assigned the d3 data attribute==10.  If d3 captured this p-tag, why not use it to display the datum?

How does d3 decide which pre-existing webpage elements to include in its “update selection”?

BTW—on d3 so far:  I feel liberated by the idea of defining data first and having the design follow.

**[ Edited:  So do I have this right?  ]**

*Based on the informative answer from @meetamit…*

The following creates an update selection inside elements

```
    elements =d3.select(“body”).selectAll(“p”).data(dataset)
```

The following causes d3 to create an enter selection where p-tags are created for 20 and 30.

```
    elements.enter() .append("p")
```

**Question:**

At this point is the update selection already merged with the enter selection?

The following sets the text in all 3 p-tags because they are all in a merged update selection.

```
    elements.text(function(d){return("#"+d);});
```

**Question:**

Since d3 will capture existing p-tags, etc from a webpage, is it common practice to make the initial d3.select point to a container that will host the d3 results, like this:

```
    elements = d3.select(“#myD3Div”)    ….
```

Comment: Did you read [Thinking with Joins](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/)?

Comment: Yes--excellent read as are the follow-on articles...read it once, but need to go over it more to "grok" it fully!

Comment: @mbostock - great article (and a great library). Would definitely be worth adding that join introduction early into the d3 docs. It's simple and clear and provides real insight into what is going on with the enter and exit steps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you call `data(dataset)` and there's one element already on the page, d3 decides that this element is to be associated with `10` -- the data of the first array element. That's because that element is the 0th `<p>` on the page and it therefore must be associated with the 0th element of your dataset. In other words, it's determining persistence based on index within the array. As a result, neither the pre-existing element nor the would-be element associated with the value `10` are returned by the `enter()` function, since they're not considered to be a new elements, just a replacement of the data associated with the existing element.

If you want it to determine persistence based on the actual data, you have to pass a 2nd param to the `data()` function:

```
data(dataset, function(d, i) { return d; })
// NOTE: "return i;" would have the same effect as not passing in the 2nd param
```

Now d3 will compare `d` in each case –– which is 10 for the 0th element and `null` for your pre-existing `<p>` -- and decide, since they're not equal, that it needs to include the 0th element in the selection returned by `enter()`, which will in turn append an element for it.

At this point, as far as d3 is concerned, the pre-existing element should be removed, and it will return it in the `exit()` selection, so you can call `remove()` on it.

Alternatively, depending on your goal, you can keep the `data()` call single-param as you have it, and update its text –– not from the `enter()` selection, but rather from the main, "updating" selection. [See this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qmEBE/1/).

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer!  Could you review my edited question to see if I understand properly?

Comment: @markE Regarding the additional questions:

1. Yes: once `append()` is called on an enter selection those elements are merged (which also entails you can update just the existing, non-entering elements if you do it before `append` is called; there's very rarely a need for that).

2. Also yes: it's common to preassign a var to single-element selection, so that later you can call `parentElement.selectAll(...).data(...)`.